# Проблема с Open Server 4.7.3

Tags: php, openserver

Не могу добавить домены, как я понял в новой версии домены автоматически подключаются из папки "domains" (так же сказано и в документации), но ничего кроме папки localhost не хочет подключаться, побывал добавить вручную - выдает ошибку запуска сервера. Что за фигня?

Answer (score 1):

Про домены правильно понял. Запускай `Open Server.exe` с правами администратора.